# get variable in included file's included file

Tags: php, variables, include

I have some files like

a.php

```
$name="X";
```

b.php

```
include "a.php";
```

c.php

```
include "b.php";
function f(){
  global $name;
  print $name;
}
```

I can't access the variable.
I would be grateful if you can help.

Comment: That should work just fine. Do you ever actually call `f()`?

Comment: are you using namespaces?

Comment: Are there any error messages, log messages or erronous output?

Comment: maybe do you want `return $name;` -> `print f();`

Comment: Thanks;) I will debug the code in deep and ask again maybe.